# AngularJS: single word input validation

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have following code:

**Javascript code**

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .config(function ($interpolateProvider) {$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}')})
        .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.word = '';
            $scope.resp = {};
            $scope.warning = '';
            $scope.get = function () {
                if($scope.word.$invalid){
                    $scope.warning = "Please write single word";
                }else {
                    $http.get("localhost/" + $scope.word)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                $scope.resp = response.data;
                            });
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

**Html code**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
    <div ng-show="word.$invalid" class="alert alert-warning">
        <strong>Warning!</strong> {[{warning}]}.
    </div>
    <input  id="filter_input" type="text" ng-model="word" ng-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]*$"/>
    <br/>
    <input id="btn" type="button" ng-click="get()" value="Check Level">
    <br/>
    <label style="text-align: center">{[{resp.level}]}</label>
</div>
```

I would like to show warning message, when user fill in input with more than one word. Could you please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on a space character - check the result:

```
var words = $scope.word.split(" ");
if (words && words.length && words.length === 1) {
    //good to go
} else {
    //error, enter only 1 word
}
```